# How to get the dirty factors of an NDB Model in pre_put_hook

Tags: app-engine-ndb, djangoappengine

Is it possible to figure the dirty factors of an entity in a `pre_put_hook`?

I want to conditionally execute some callbacks based on what is being `put`. E.g. if an entity has a particular property changed, I want to send a mail notification. I can do that manually before calling `put()` but if the method fails  then the `put()` doesn't get called either.

Answer (score 2):

Following [Brian M. Hunt suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31053342/1822624), I check the dirty factors using the following code. In this case, I check a property called `status`:

```
class Blog(ndb.Model):
  status = ndb.IntegerProperty(default=0)

  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # make sure the __old_status__ exists when you `new' an object
    # instead of getting it from DataStore. e.g. b = Blog(status=1)
    super(Blog, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.__old_status__ = self.status # I check the status only

  @classmethod
  def _post_get_hook(cls, key, future):
    obj = future.get_result()
    setattr(obj, '__old_status__', obj.status)

  def _pre_put_hook(self):
    if (not self.key.id() or self.__old_status__ != self.status)  and (self.status == 1):
      # the blog is (either a new blog or an existing blog) AND its status is changed to published (e.g. value = 1)
      # do sth e.g. save the time when it is published, update FB object cache and etc.
      pass
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I haven't touched this project in years and unfortunately have no way to verify that this answer is correct (without relearning all of how NDB works), so I can't mark it as accepted. Upvoting as a thank you though until some good netizen comes along and verifies that this a good answer!

Comment: I have verified that this solution works and is an acceptable answer.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, this is not an NDB feature.

Comment: Can you suggest an alternative way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

You could do this by defining on your `ndb.Model` a `_post_get_hook` and a `_pre_put_hook` that respectively save the original value of the property and compare the value being put to the original.